# Toggle class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I would need to hide a div when user clicks a link.

The html is something like this:

```
<div class="item">
<div class="entry">
Lorem ipsum
</div>
<a href="#" class="commentsToggle">Show/hide comments</a>
<div class="comments hidden">
This comments div I want show/hide
</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
<div class="entry">
Lorem ipsum
</div>
<a href="#" class="commentsToggle">Show/hide comments</a>
<div class="comments hidden">
This comments div I want show/hide
</div>
</div>

....there's multiple items after this
```

As a default the comments are hidden (hence the class hidden there). Now if user clicks the Show/hide comments link it should show or hide comments for that specific item, depending are they visible or not. Now the question is do I need some id's to control js to hook only to that one specicif items ocmments and can I do it witouh id?

The js is something like atm:

```
$('.item .commentsToggle').click(function(){
        elem = $(this).parents('.item');

        $(elem).find('.comments').each(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
        });
    });
```

If there's only one item that works but if multiple it breaks up :/

This is pretty simple.. I just dont get it into my head how to do it actually :D

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with the code, it is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/qMAWP/4/

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/uB9Fb/

try this JS:

```
$('.commentsToggle').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".comments").toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the current structure of each post, the shortest way to do it is

```
$('.item .commentsToggle').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

But a more general way is like you're suggesting

```
$('.item .commentsToggle').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.item').find('.comments').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Also note that you should use the `.on()` function to bind events as of jQuery 1.7, even though older functions still work.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like following

```
  $('.item .commentsToggle').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.comments').toggleClass('hidden');
   });
```

and if you have more comments you can use the following

```
   $('.item .commentsToggle').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.item').children('.comments').toggleClass('hidden');
   });
```