# How to make a simple jQuery button that toggles an element's background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know it probably doesn't get any simpler than this but hey I am a novice. I just want to use the `bgtoggle` class as a simple change of state button that changes the background color of `metro` class. I know I am using the wrong approach because what I am trying is not working. Any help is very appreciated! Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="bgtoggle">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bgtoggle{
    position: absolute;
    width: 56px;
    height: 43px;
    right:65px;
    top:170px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 3em;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:9999;
    background-image: url("../images/mthc/bgtoggle.png");
    background-size: 100%;
}

.bgtoggle:hover{
    background-image: url("../images/mthc/bgtoggle2.png");
}
```

And I have this attempt at jQuery which of course is not doing as intended:

```
$('.bgtoggle').toggle(function () {
    $(".metro").css('background', '#000');
}, function () {
    $(".metro")css('background', '#fff'));
}
```

Comment: That version of jQuery's `toggle()` function was deprecated and removed from jQuery a few years ago

Comment: ↑ ↑ ↑ Use click instead and handle logic inside handler

Comment: You want it to change just for the moment it is clicked, or do you want a permanent state change?  If you want it just for the moment, you can just  use the :active pseudo class.

Comment: oooh please exaplin yes i want it to be able to change permenantly until it is clicked again

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click toggle with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467228/click-toggle-with-jquery)

Comment: nope , i don't want to use a checkbox thanks

Comment: @havingagoatit, it is the same principle as in the possible duplicate link, just change the part (for checked ) to what you need. The main idea is to use click instead of toggle

Comment: Need a . On the second css. $('.metro').css

Comment: it didn't work just changing the code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle class with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295534/toggle-class-with-jquery)

Comment: Dude a simple google search for "toggling a class with jquery" would give you plenty of examples. This is an old problem that has long been solved and by resorting to asking a stack overflow question you are burning peoples time because this will be flagged as a dupe and closed. The people that answer are trolling for easy points. I'm not saying don't ask questions. Do ask questions. Just put in some effort first. Posting a question on stack overflow should be your last resort.

Comment: it was a last resort and google searches did not return the desired answer, ... you need to READ THE WHOLE PAGE -- answer below is different from suggested duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a button, based on your CSS (except the background image which I do not have) and made it change the body's background color instead, so as to provide you with a very visual effect. I know you can take this and apply it whichever way you like. One thing to note, I am using the latest jQuery version here, which means that instead of `$` you need to use `jQuery`, that can be changed back if you wish to use an earlier version.

[jsFiddle_1](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/o6o6xazc/)

HTML

```
<div class="bgtoggle"></div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".bgtoggle").click(function () {
        jQuery("body").toggleClass("bgcolor--yellow");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
body {
    /* set the background to whatever you like, I made it white in color */
    background-color: white;
}

.bgcolor--yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I noted that you had a few syntax errors on your end to begin with (normal if you are a beginner no big deal). Such as not checking for the document (the webpage) to be ready. I also considered that if you want a button, you will want an on click event to represent a button functionality.

If you really wanted to achieve this via hover, then use mouseover/mouseout instead:

[jsFiddle_2](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/rzz8x15d/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".bgtoggle").mouseover(function () {
        jQuery("body").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
    jQuery(".bgtoggle").mouseout(function () {
        jQuery("body").css("background-color", "white");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... the first example is kinda what I am looking for but you can only do the change once to yellow... i want to be able to turn the yellow on and off whenever i click... I have a url background img for one state and yellow for the other for example

Comment: that sounds doable, let me modify the fiddle for you, stand by :)

Comment: thanks AGE you are the only one that seems to understand what i am trying to do

Comment: that's because people are trying to help, but they aren't putting the effort to explain, if they did I bet they would have given you similar answers to what I made.

Comment: yes i think you are right , it is a shame as I am sure they are capable , perhaps a good teacher knows things, a great teacher relates information as well as knowing ;)

Comment: very well said mate, let me now if this helped you and if it did (better than anyone else) accept it for the future generations to follow

Comment: yes it certainly worked on the jsfiddle and putting the code in I am now changing the class body to .metro and the toggle class to a background color from the original url img used and hoepfully it will change between those two things , an image and a color on click every time

Comment: having a bit of trouble as I am changing from a normal bg color to the img url that was stored in .metro (body) in the first place ... going to try a couple of things first

Comment: no problem! I thought I might comment by saying, you need to change background-color to background, then specify background: url("....") for your initial image, then change it to background: "yellow" or something to your needs for the click event. Glad to know this worked for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about How to make a toggle button using jQuery and It perform action whenever toggle event takes place, take a look at the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Toggle Button using Jquery</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:.9em;">
<center>
<div class="metro" style="width:100;height:100;background-color: rgb(255,  255, 255);">To change Me</div>
<div class="bgtoggle" style="width:100;height:100;cursor:pointer;">Click Here</div>
<script>

$('.bgtoggle').click(function() {
   if ($('.metro').css('background-color')=="rgb(255, 255, 255)"){
       $('.metro').css('background-color', '#000');
   } else if ($('.metro').css('background-color')=="rgb(0, 0, 0)"){
       $('.metro').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
   }
});

</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Best of luck for your project!